# Can I connect a Amazon SQL RDS instance in remote desktop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rdp

I want to connect an Amazon SQL RDS instance in RDP... But there is no credentials supplied by AWS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. RDS does not allow access to the underlying instance at all. This is part of the deal when you opt for a managed service. You give up some of the control in return for someone else taking care of the infrastructure.

If you need access to the host machine you would need to run the database on your own EC2 instance(s).

Comment: This is now possible see Paolo's answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you now can access RDS managed instances via RDP if you use RDS Custom.
This new offering, introduced recently, allows you to leverage the benefits of RDS while still being able to access the underlying instances.

At this time, Amazon RDS Custom supports Oracle Database and Microsoft SQL Server engines.

You can find more information at the [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-custom.html).

Answer (score 0):

I read several times, check the documentation. The only one i see that can be remotely connected to using RDP is EC2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).